# build a c++ program with makefile in windows

Tags: c++, windows, shell, boost, cygwin

I wrote a little c++ program with visual studio. 
I have to build that program with a shell script. For that I installed cygwin. How can I build a program, that uses an environment variable for the boost-library?

Comment: Installing Cygwin sounds like serious overkill. Visual Studio comes with  a "make" utility called `nmake`, and a more heavy-weight general build system (the one used by Visual Studio itself) called `msbuild`. But you don't need either tool to build your little program in a shell script: just create a Windows batch file with the build command. A batch file is a shell script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I actually want to use the gnu compiler.

Comment: The answer is the same with g++, except the additional, that installing Cygwin is overkill and overcomplex for just using g++ in Windows. Install some MinGW distro instead. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install boost from http://www.boost.org/users/download/
2. I'm not sure of the system that you use to compile C++ but thing is for sure, you need to create a **makefile** for your program.
3. After **makefile** is created, add to the flags the following:

   -lboost_system -lboost_locale

Good luck!